Spatie/Browsershot (Puppeteer) is printing out binary data instead of base64 (PDF)
I'm using Spatie/Browsershot in Laravel to generate PDFs in Base64 format. In my local machine (Windows), it works without any issues. However, in my Ubuntu server (AWS), it doesn't. It just prints out some numbers which I believe to be raw binary data.
The code I'm using for my local host:
$base64Data = Browsershot::html(view('receipt-pdf', ['data' => $receipt, 'pmData' => $pmData])->render())
                ->setNodeBinary("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node")
                ->setNpmBinary("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\npm")
                ->setChromePath('C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe')
                ->format('A4')
                ->base64pdf();

Example output:
JVBERi0xLjQKJdPr6eEKMSAwIG9iago8PC9UaXRsZSAoQXFhcmkgLSA3KQovQ3JlYXRvciAoTW96aWxsYS81LjAgXChXaW5kb3dzIE5UIDEwLjA7IFdpbjY0OyB4NjRcKSBBcHBsZVdlYkt...
And for my Ubuntu server:
$base64Data = Browsershot::html(view('receipt-pdf', ['data' => $receipt, 'pmData' => $pmData])->render())
                ->setChromePath('/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable')
                ->format('A4')
                ->base64pdf();

Example output:
37,80,68,70,45,49,46,52,10,37,211,235,233,225,10,49,32,48,32,111,98,106,10,60,60,47,84,105,116,108,......
I have checked the following:

Permissions regarding the execution of Chrome.
Using Chromium instead of Chrome.
Re-installing Chrome.
Generating with ->pdf() instead of ->base64pdf() and then using base64_encode().

None of those worked.

after alot of investigation around this:
browsershot installs the latest puppeteer version, it causes bad communication between puppeeter and browsershot, because it doesn't return base64 format
see:
https://github.com/spatie/browsershot/commit/a270f121c844c246ce8944d17c1d2d4c9432ef01
Solution is PHP >= 8.2 && update your composer to "spatie/browsershot": "^4.3.0"
or if you want to handle it by your version:
    $base64Data = Browsershot::html(view('receipt-pdf', ['data' => $receipt, 'pmData' => $pmData])->render())
                    ->setNodeBinary("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node")
                    ->setNpmBinary("C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\npm")
                    ->setChromePath('C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe')
                    ->format('A4')
                    ->base64pdf();

 $result =  $this->encodeCommaSeparatedNumbersToBase64($result);

/**
     * This is made because of the issue with the Browsershot library
     * https://github.com/spatie/browsershot/commit/a270f121c844c246ce8944d17c1d2d4c9432ef01
     * which loaded the latest version of the puppeteer library , this is caused issue with the pdf generation
     * @param $pdf
     * @return string
     */
    public function encodeCommaSeparatedNumbersToBase64($pdf) : string
    {
        if (preg_match('/^[0-9,]+$/', $pdf)) {
            $intNumbers = array_map('intval', explode(',', $pdf));
            $pdfBinaryData = implode('', array_map('chr', $intNumbers));
            return base64_encode($pdfBinaryData);
        }
        return $pdf;
    }

